# Integrate Testfairy SDK into my xamarin project

Tags: c#, testfairy

Can anyone please tell me how to integrate testfairty SDK into my xanmarin project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of using the TestFairy SDK with Xamarin:

1. Downloading the .dlls from github.
2. Downloading bindings using nuget
3. Downloading using the Xamarin Component Store (Recommended.)

You can find documentation at:

- https://docs.testfairy.com/Platforms/Xamarin_Component.html
- https://docs.testfairy.com/Platforms/Xamarin.html